# airflow UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2

Tags: airflow

I installed airflow: `pip install apache-airflow`, `airflow initdb` and started the airflow webserver `airflow webserver -p 8080` but when I try to open the home page, I keep getting the error message:
`UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)`

I even tried a different version `1.10.1`, I got the same issue.

Here's the full stacktrace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/dbrown/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/sync.py", line 135, in handle
    self.handle_request(listener, req, client, addr)
  File "/Users/dbrown/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/sync.py", line 176, in handle_request
    respiter = self.wsgi(environ, resp.start_response)
  File "/Users/dbrown/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/wsgi.py", line 826, in __call__
    return app(environ, start_response)
  File "/Users/dbrown/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1997, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/Users/dbrown/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1985, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "/Users/dbrown/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1547, in handle_exception
    return self.finalize_request(handler(e), from_error_handler=True)
  File "/Users/dbrown/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/airflow/www/views.py", line 708, in show_traceback
    info=traceback.format_exc()), 500
  File "/Users/dbrown/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/templating.py", line 134, in render_template
    context, ctx.app)
  File "/Users/dbrown/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/templating.py", line 116, in _render
    rv = template.render(context)
  File "/Users/dbrown/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 989, in render
    return self.environment.handle_exception(exc_info, True)
  File "/Users/dbrown/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 754, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/Users/dbrown/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/airflow/www/templates/airflow/traceback.html", line 27, in top-level template code
    {{ nukular }}Node: {{ hostname }}
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Here's my system information:

```
:~ $ python --version
Python 2.7.13 :: Anaconda, Inc.


:~ $ sw_vers
ProductName:    Mac OS X
ProductVersion: 10.14.6
BuildVersion:   18G87
```

Answer (score 0):

I re-installed anaconda python and the airflow issue disappeared. My current python version:

```
:~ $ python --version
Python 2.7.13 :: Anaconda 4.3.0 (x86_64)
```